# Aws alterar instancia EC2 de uma região para outra

Tags: amazon-aws

Eu criei todas as minhas instancias em Oregon, existe uma maneira de pelo ADM eu migrar para Virginia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não existe uma maneira simples de fazer isto, mas você pode seguir este roteiro, no próprio AWS Console (web adm):

1. Criar a imagem de cada instância
2. Transformar esta imagem em um modelo disponível na nova região
3. Criar outra instância na nova região a partir do modelo

Comment: Bom dia!!!
Você teria alguma documentação da transferência de região de uma instancia na Aws Ec2?

Comment: A documentação é esta resposta, apenas 3 passos. Cada um destes passos possui sua própria documentação